# How do I override CSS styles properly?

Tags: html, css

I use a design CSS framework that styles all HTML elements.

For example, styling all tables:

```
table.table.tablelist-custom-style>tbody>tr>td.tr-title-gray {
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border-top: 2px solid #9c27b0;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

How do I correctly override this style?

I have set a class `new`:

```
<tr class="tr-title new">
```

**CSS:**

```
.new td {
    background: red;
}
```

But there is no effect,  the td still has a default background. If I check it in Chrome I see that `.new` present but striked out.

Property `!important` works for me, but I know it is a bad practice

How do I override CSS styles properly?

Yes, I can do this:

```
table.table.tablelist-custom-style>tbody>tr.new {
  background: red;
}
```

But this way brings duplicates of CSS rules.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: This is really a code review question and doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. That said, you will definitely have to make a long selector rule (as know, using `!important` isn't the best practice), since your first rule is so specific. Also, you should update your question since you are asking about styles that apply to a `td`, but then say `tr`.

Comment: Why not just use `td.tr-title-gray { styles }` and then `td.tr-title-gray.new { }`. Do you need that long of a selector in the first place?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it could potentially go into https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: could be that you are linking the design framework after your CSS or as @disinforc said you need to be more [specific](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Comment: Html is in question , it is table tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Specificity** is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration, determined by the number of each selector type in the matching selector. When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

You can't overwrite those styles easily without `!import` because calculated weight of `table.table.tablelist-custom-style>tbody>tr.new` is much higher than `.new td`.

Experienced developers use BEM or other standardized methods of writing styles to avoid that problem. If you can't change the first rule from your post you are forced to use a more complicated selector (for example `.new.new.new.new.new.new td`) or `important`.